# Change selected link color using CSS?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've defined a class (item1) for a set of objects.

Is it possible to put red text color the object (from the class) that I click/select and put all the other objects (from the class) in black text color?

Here's is the code where I apply the class (item1):

```
        <td>
            <a class="item1" href="/menu2" onclick="">
            Menu1
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a class="item1" href="/menu2" onclick="">
            Menu2
            </a>
        </td>
```

How can I do this in the css file?

Comment: Only css?? No javascript??

Comment: Javascript possible as well :)

Comment: Is it possible to put red text color the object (from the class) that I click/select? No. using javascript also - yes

Comment: We use this in our project's and it will do trick for you unless you are using any third party libraries like bootstrap, check this also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzY2j/)!

And here's the code:

**HTML**

```
<td>
            <a class="item1" href="#">
            Menu1
            </a>
        </td>

        <td>
            <a class="item1" href="#">
            Menu2
            </a>
        </td>
```

**JS**

```
$('.item1').click(function(e){
    $('.item1').css("color", "black");
    $(this).css("color", "red");
});
```

Answer (score 6):

> Is it possible to put red text color the object (from the class) that
>   I click/select

OK some of the terms you're using need a bit of clarity:

- On click in css is called `:active`
- On hover in css is called
  `:hover`
- After click in css is called `:visited` when talking about
  an `a` tag.

If you mean to actually set a link to an "active" state, you may have "symptoms" of that with the `:visited` selector, but it is by no means the way to do that.

the real way to do that is to physically add a class to your element that will identify it as active, i.e. `<a class="active">` and style that particular class accordingly (typically done with a sprinkling of javascript)

**So, using javascript how do you add / remove that class?**

Using javascript, you listen to click events. every time something is clicked, you do the following:

1. remove the existing `active` class from whatever element currently
   holds it.
2. add it to the item being clicked.

Comment: But I want to revert to black if I click on other. This do that?

Comment: here I just wanted to share this ... that I found recently: http://css-tricks.com/overriding-the-default-text-selection-color-with-css/ , I know it is not the answer to this question, but the title just reminded me of it =)

Answer (score 4):

You might be looking for `:visited`

```
a:visited {

color:red;

}
```

Comment: But I want to revert to black if I click on other. This do that?

Comment: @Wezly what you've suggested is precisely what I warned against when I said that using `:visited` as an indicator of an active state is merely a symptom of a post click, and is by no means the right way to do that

Comment: Then you should consider using Javascript, @Kristian The question stated HTML and CSS only, Happy to provide a JS example if the question changes.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using ajax, or loading your content in another frame, the best is using javascript (jquery):

```
$('a').each(function(){
   $(this).click(function(){
      $('a').removeClass('selected');
      $(this).addClass('selected');
   })
});
```

in your style:

```
a, a:hover, a:visited, a:active{
   color:black;
}
a.selected{
   color: red;
}
```