# Top Hover border color is switched to default when the mouse is moved to the UL LI list

Tags: html, css, dom

I really need your help,

How can the code be modified below so as to allow the border color to remain blue while the user makes a selection in the UL LI list?

Here is a capture of the problem:

[image]

Here is a picture of the expected result:

[image]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/g825e2o2/

CSS Markup:

```
<style type="text/css">
   * {
    font-family: Segoe UI;
    font-size: 9pt;
}
.select dd, .select dt, .select ul {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
.select dd {
    position: relative;
}
.select a, .select a:visited {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    outline: none;
}
.select dt a:hover, .select dt a:focus {
    /*border: 1px solid red; */
}
.select dd ul li a:hover {
    background-color: rgb(112,146,190);
    color: #FFF;
}

.select dt a {
    background: url(arrow.png) no-repeat scroll right center;
    display: block;
    padding-right: 20px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    width: 180px;
}
.select dt a span {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    padding: 4px;
    height: 15px;
}
.select dd ul {
    background:#fff none repeat scroll 0 0;
    border-bottom:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    border-left:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    border-right:1px solid rgb(170,170,170);
    border-top:0;
    display:none;
    left:0px;
    padding:5px 0px;
    position:absolute;
    top:-1px;
    width:auto;
    min-width:200px;
    list-style:none;
}
.select dd ul:hover, .select dt a:hover, .select dt a:focus {
    border-color: blue;
}
.select dd ul li a {
    padding-left:10px;
    padding-top:3px;
    padding-bottom: 3px;
    display:block;
}
.selected{
    background: rgb(195,195,195);
}
.header-list {
    padding-left: 3px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-style: italic;
}
</style>
```

The rest of the HTML:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {


    $(".select dt a").click(function() {
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');
        select.find('ul').toggle();
        //$(this).css("background-color", "rgb(255,255,196)");

    });

    $(".select dd ul li a").click(function(e) {
        var text = $(this).html();
        var select = $(this).closest('.select');

        if (e.ctrlKey) {

            $(this).addClass('selected');

            select.find('dt span').html("(" + select.find('a.selected').length + ")")

        }
        else {
            var text = $(this).html();
            select.find("dd a").removeClass('selected');
            $(this).addClass('selected');

            select.find("dt span").html(text);

            select.find("dt a").css("background-color", "");

            select.find("dd ul").hide();
        }

    });

    $(document).bind('click', function(e) {
        var $clicked = $(e.target);
        if (!$clicked.parents().hasClass("select"))
            $(".select dd ul").hide();
    });

});
</script>

</head>

<body>

    <dl id="reqtype" class="select">Fruits
        <dt><a href="#"><span data-val=""></span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a data-val="" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                    <span class="header-list">- List -</span>
                <li><a data-val="apples" href="#">Apples</a></li>
                <li><a data-val="Bananas" href="#">Bananas</a></li>
                <li><a data-val="Oranges" href="#">Oranges</a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>

    <br><br>

    <dl id="action" class="select">Status
        <dt><a href="#"><span data-val=""></span></a></dt>
        <dd>
            <ul>
                <li><a data-val="" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                <li><a data-val="ACTIVE" href="#">ACTIVE</a></li>
                <li><a data-val="ON HOLD" href="#">ON HOLD</a></li>
                <li><a data-val="CLOSED" href="#">CLOSED</a></li>
            </ul>
        </dd>
    </dl>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It looks like that you've already solved it.

Comment: May I ask why your are not using a simple <select> for this? Unless you have a very specific use case this seems like reinventing the wheel.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, using a little JavaScript snippet from here can do the job. You'll simply have to add the following code to your JS file (you can customize it as you wish):

```
$('.fruit').click(function(e){
    $(this).css("background-color", "red");
    $(this).css("color", "white");
});
```

Then, in your HTML file, add the "fruit" class to each link of the list you want this behavior to apply to, like this:

```
<dl id="reqtype" class="select">Fruits
    <dt><a href="#"><span data-val=""></span></a></dt>
    <dd>
        <ul>
            <li><a data-val="" href="#">&nbsp;</a></li>
                <span class="header-list">- List -</span>
            <li><a class="fruit" data-val="apples" href="#">Apples</a></li>
            <li><a class="fruit" data-val="Bananas" href="#">Bananas</a></li>
            <li><a class="fruit" data-val="Oranges" href="#">Oranges</a></li>
        </ul>
    </dd>
</dl>
```

That should do the trick ;)
Of course, the JavaScript snippet can be adapted to suit your CSS needs.

Inspired from the solution to [that question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118325/change-selected-link-color-using-css).