# What is the best practice to self-detect clicked menu item for each page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, navigation, navbar

If there are many pages share a same menu

```
    include_once('common-menu.php');
```

But the menu should have some different for different page

Page A

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="active"><a href="a.php">A Page</a></li>
    <li><a href="b.php">B Page</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Page B

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li><a href="a.php">A Page</a></li>
    <li class="active"><a href="b.php">B Page</a></li>
  </ul>
```

I only know two solutions.

Solution 1: Server side to detect the URL then determine the output

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="<? echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="a.php">A Page</a></li>
    <li class=""><a href="b.php">B Page</a></li>
  </ul>


  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class=""><a href="a.php">A Page</a></li>
    <li class="<? echo 'active'; ?>"><a href="b.php">B Page</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Solution 2: Use js/jquery to detect the URL, and then change the class by js/jquery after the page loaded.

What is the best practice for this problem?

Is there any non-programmatic solution so that I don't need to use if/case/map to determine the active item?

Comment: Try this technique: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an almost pure css solution but it's not ideal. Output the url as a parent id and use selectors to handle the rest. The downsides to this is it becomes tedious if you need to add a lot of navigation items. It would be much better to use one of the above solutions.

PHP

```
<div id="<? basename($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], ".php") ?>">
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li><a href="a.php">A Page</a></li>
        <li><a href="b.php">B Page</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#a .nav a[href$='a.php'],#b .nav a[href$='b.php']{    
    color:red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

On the PHP side, you could do something like this using the built-in PHP `currPage()` function:

```
<li class="menu-item <?php chk_active('myprojects.php');?>"><a href="myprojects.php">Projects</a></li>
<li class="menu-item <?php chk_active('invoicehistory.php');?>"><a href="invoicehistory.php">Invoice History</a></li>
```

And the chk_active() function looks like this:

```
function chk_active($chkPage){
    if (currPage()==$chkPage) {
        echo 'active';
    }else if (currPage()=='project.php' && $chkPage=='myprojects.php'){
        echo 'active';
    }
}
```