# How to keep underlined?

Tags: html, css

I was wondering how to keep a Navigation tab underlined while I am on that page. Here's an example of what I'm talking about.

http://www.ferrari.com/en_us/auto

Do you see how Auto is underlined? If you click on News then News will be underlined.

Comment: Honestly this question has so many different possible answers it's not even funny.  Give us some code you already tried so we can at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: On that particular site it's just a `class="current"`, most probably determined by the current address/webpage loaded, which is also `auto` as the link itself suggests.

Comment: Do you think this involves Javascript or can you do it with just css and html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please see this Stack Overflow link:
[jQuery add class .active on menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu)

It has many different solutions to add a class to your active link (and then you can apply underline style to that class).