# Create active menu point in navigation

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following HTML structure:

```
<div>
    <ul id="Category" class="row list-inline">                
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars">
                Cars
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars%20Racer">
                Cars MVC
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Bikes">
                Bikes
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Rollers">
                Rollers
            </a>
        </li>                
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Scooters">
                Scooters
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Clicking on the hyperlink navigates to that respective page (postback). I want to change the background color of the link which got clicked.

I have written the following script for the same:

```
$("#Category li").click(function () {
    $("#Category li > a").each(function () {
        $(this).removeClass("selectedan")
    });
    $(this).addClass("selectedan");
});
```

But with no effect. What seems to be wrong?

Comment: Just to get some clarity here: Is the page reloading or are you reloading the content for your postback asynchronously?

Comment: The entire page gets reloaded

Comment: Cool. So none of these answers are going to work for you because you're reloading the page synchronously. The Javascript will fire before the page reloads.

Comment: yes exactly, with the page reload, it all goes.

Comment: There is no need of JQuery here, as Page is getting reloaded, you can do it by CSS

Comment: Did you get what you needed @Hitz?

Comment: No not yet. I am trying your solution and it does look very promising but haven't got it to work yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I'd handle it given the codesnippet you've given us and knowing that your entire page refreshes:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#Category li > a").each(function () {
    if ($(this).attr('href') === window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '')) {
      $(this).addClass("selectedan");
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<div>
    <ul id="Category" class="row list-inline">                
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars">
                Cars
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Cars%20Racer">
                Cars MVC
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Bikes">
                Bikes
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Rollers">
                Rollers
            </a>
        </li>                
        <li>
            <a href="/products/Category/Scooters">
                Scooters
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Can't guarantee the above will work exactly, but you'll want to do the following concepts:

- On page load, loop over each navigation anchor
- Check that the pathname matches the href

  - If they match, add the class
  - If they don't, do nothing

Comment: There are two issues I am unable to resolve due to an ending slash. window.location.pathname adds an ending '\' so the two strings never are equal. Second issue is the %20 in Cars%20Racer.

Comment: I've updated my solution to fix the pathname, what's the problem with the `%20` in `Cars%20Racer`?

Comment: Your jQuery is a lot more compact. Nice!

Comment: I'd probably extract the conditional out into a sensibly named function such as `function isCurrentPage(anchorHref) { return anchorHref === window.location.pathname.replace(/\//, '' }` and change the conditional to `if (isCurrentPage($(this).attr('href'))) { ... }` if I were to write it for myself. It's not _super_ intuitive what's happening in the code otherwise. 

Comment: Your code 'almost' worked. This is what I had to do to make it work if ($(this).attr('href').replace(/\//g, '') === window.location.pathname.replace(/\//g, ''))

Comment: Doh. That's a bad regular expression. Are you familiar with them and what this one is doing? That's totally my bad, the replace should be `/\/$/`, otherwise with your flag it'll replace every `/` which you don't want. :) If you change the `pathname` expression to the `$` regexp and remoove the first replace, it _should_ work just fine.

Comment: Yes that worked. By the way you are missing a closing ')' after replace. Please correct your answer if ($(this).attr('href') === window.location.pathname.replace(/\/$/, '')) {

Comment: All set. Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
$("#Category li").click(function () {
    $("a .selectedan").removeClass("selectedan");
    $(this).addClass("selectedan");
});
```

Comment: This will work but the `.selectedan` class is applied to the `li` not the `a`, so I think it should be `$(".selectedan").removeClass("selectedan");`

Comment: Doesn't actually answer the OP's question. There's a thread explaining the page does a refresh, so this answer isn't correct for the question.

Answer (score -1):

If you want the menu-point to have a background-color after navigating to it, just add a CSS-class called `active` (or something similar) to the specific menu-point. In CSS you can then set a styling for that `a`-tag with a `active`-class.

```
.active {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

See the [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/0mxv9bxh/1/), where I added `class="active"` to the Bikes-link.

Now, as it comes to adding the `active` class to the menu points, you have two possibilities:

1. Manually add the class `active` to every menu point, copy/pasting the menu to every page and having quite a risk on making a mistake
2. Use the following piece of code:

.

```
$(function(){
       var url = window.location.pathname, 
       urlRegExp = new RegExp(url.replace(/\/$/,'') + "$"); // create regexp to match current url pathname and remove trailing slash    if present as it could collide with the link in navigation in case    trailing slash wasn't present there
       // now grab every link from the navigation
       $('#category li a').each(function(){
          // and test its normalized href against the url pathname regexp
          if(urlRegExp.test(this.href.replace(/\/$/,''))){
              $(this).addClass('active');
          }
       });    });
```

Edited from [source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu). It might not work 100% on your project, so you might be able to adapt it so it works.

Comment: I tried it but with the page reload there is no effect

Comment: Ah like that. Give me two seconds

Comment: Unfortunately, that's not how the `:active` pseudo-selector works. "It allows the page to give a feedback that the activation has been detected by the browser." and does not apply to a place based on the active URL. (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%3Aactive)

Comment: @chaseadamsio It works exactly as the OP wrote: When clicked, it gives something a background. However, he wasn't clear it also needed to have the background when the page reloaded, which is why I added some more info to my answer.

Comment: That's fair, but leaving your SO answer of 'use `:active`' still isn't a correct answer based on the response the OP gave in the questions to the question.

Comment: @chaseadamsio removed it.

Comment: Thanks. I might also suggest giving a recommendation of how to add the class rather than just suggesting adding the class. It seems like the OP understood that they needed to add a class to the active anchor and suggesting google doesn't ensure the OP will find the solution you might think is the "best" solution.

Comment: Also done. The answer can probably not get more of a solution than it is now ;)

Comment: Thanks! That's close to how I was approaching it, but since you've got the upvote yours will show before mine does, so I'm glad there's a good solution for when someone less savvy with using SO finds something that works well. Solid work.