# menu highlighted after clicked

Tags: jquery, css

Im in need of a little help. when the user goes onto the application page for example. the icon needs to stay lit up. in the image my cursor is hovered over it to give the efffect. anyone know if what i want to achieve is possible.

```
<ul class="mid-menu center-align">

        <li>
            <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/account/'; ?>">
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>account.svg" alt="account page" />
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-account.png" alt="account page" />
                <span>My Account</span>
            </a>
        </li>

        <?php
        if ( THEME == 'stafforce_onlinereg' || THEME == 'stafforce_perm_portal' ) {
        ?>
            <li>
                <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/details/'; ?>">
                    <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>profile.svg" alt="account page" />
                    <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-profile.png" alt="account page" />
                    <span>Candidate Profile</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
        } else {
        ?>
            <li>
                <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/cvupload/'; ?>">
                    <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>profile.svg" alt="account page" />
                    <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-profile.png" alt="account page" />
                    <span>CV Upload</span>
                </a>
            </li>
        <?php
        }
        ?>

        <li>
            <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/basket/'; ?>">
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>basket.svg" alt="account page" />
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-basket.png" alt="account page" />
                <span>Job Basket <?=$this->formatBasketCount($this->basketCount)?></span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/applications/'; ?>">
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>applications.svg" alt="account page" />
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-app.png" alt="account page" />
                <span>Application</span>
            </a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a class="bannernav-link " href="/<?php echo APP_URL . 'portal/downloads/'; ?>">
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-L" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>downloads.svg" alt="account page" />
                <img class="bannernav-img nav-M" src="<?php echo THEME_IMG_PATH; ?>mobile-downloads.png" alt="account page" />
                <span>Downloads</span>
            </a>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

[image: target]

Comment: Check out this thread to figure out how to add a class to your menu item: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4866284/jquery-add-class-active-on-menu

Answer (score 1):

suppose your style is `color:white`

you need to give class on the icon corresponding to active page

and then do

```
.activeTab {
  color: white;
}
```